# How to replace an output filename by a custom command that use output?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, pipe

Say I have a command `cmd` that is creating a new filename given as argument:

For instance,

```
cmd -w /root/myfile
```

**How to change this expression in order to use a custom command that use the file output directly instead of writting the file.**

I don't want to write the file and then trigger a command on it but put the  output of `cmd` directly in the new custom command.

For instance, instead of creating the file and then running

```
 cat myfile | gpg -e > myfile.gpg
```

I am looking for expression that is directly encrypting the output.

The solution is probably in using a block device like

```
(cmd -w /dev/device) & (dd if=/dev/device | gpg -e > myfile.gpg)
```

Fifo do not always work.

Comment: If you cannot alter the code, the best option I see is to write a wrapper, running your command, waiting for the file to appear, run the gpg stuff and delete the original file.

Answer (score 4):

Bash allows using the construction `/dev/fd/`*fd*  to refer to the file with file descriptor *fd*; standard input is `/dev/fd/0`, standard output is `/dev/fd/1`, etc., and of course you can open other file descriptors.

This means that if you have a command *cmdname* which cannot output to standard output but accepts a `-o` *filename* option, you can make it write to standard output with

```
cmdname -o /dev/fd/1
```

Answer (score 0):

`gpg` can accept input from and output to either streams or files. If you can use the first command without the -w flag, and avoid having to create a file, so long as your command is outputting to stdout you can use:

```
cmd  | gpg -e -o /path/to/myfile.gpg
```

Which will directly write your encrypted information to the file, without creating an intermediate file.

Comment: I understand it is not writing to stdout, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I just reread the question and edited to try to reflect it, I think, like you said, if it's not possible to change the code, and avoid the `-w` option, it's not going to be possible. Not sure whether it's worth leaving this here or to delete.

Comment: Let's see ehat happens :)

Answer (score 0):

write a bash function which takes filename as positional argument `$1`.  That way your 3 commands condense to one.

```
encrypt(){
cmd -w "$1"
cat "$1" | gpg -e > "$1".gpg
}
```

Place this into .bashrc, run `source ~/.bashrc`, and use as

```
encrypt myfile
```